# Optimal Kolmogorov complexity

Tags: information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

Let computable function U is the best way to describe to Kolmogorov complexity. Prove that the mapping V, determined crucial for any word p as V (p) = U (U (p)), is also optimal
way to describe the.

Please tell me in which direction to think.